# Updating component's state using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update some component's state using received props in this manner:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if(nextProps.history.length <= 2) {
      this.setState({
         history: nextProps.history
      });
   }
}
```

The problem is that when a parent passes a history with a length bigger than 2, the state is still mutating. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: _..when a parent passes a history with a length bigger than 2, the state is still mutating._ -- Are you sure the state update happens only from this `componentWillReceiveProps` hook?

Comment: You should also check if the nextProps is different from the Props. If no, there is no need to update your state.

Comment: Arup - yes, this is the only place where my components' state could mutate...

Comment: a codesandbox will help here to debug

Comment: Here is the answer (friend of mine helped me with that):
When passing some "big object" (not primitive like integer or char), the browser passes the object by reference rather than copying it. That's the problem. So the solution is - pass a copy (either deep or not) if you don't want to be depend on changes made somewhere else in your code

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle method [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) is deprecated. You should use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method or the 
static `getDerivedStateFromProps()` method.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return ({
        history: props.history.length <= 2 ? props.history : state.history
    })
}
```

Or if you prefer:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    if((prevProps.history !== history) && history.length <= 2) {
        this.setState({ history })
    }
}
```